# NavigationView icons + text in compact mode

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui, uwp-navigation

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the image below where in compact mode you have the icon and the text displayed under it.

[image: Navigation view with icons and text]

I'm not that familiar with modifying the underlying template for the `NavigationView` to make this work. Can you give me an advice on how to do this?

The code for the `NavigationView` is pretty much the default one:

```
<winui:NavigationView
    x:Name="navigationView"
    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
    IsBackEnabled="False"
    IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False"
    IsSettingsVisible="False"
    PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}">
    <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage">
            <winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE80F;" />
            </winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_WorkOrders" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:WorkOrdersPage">
            <winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE9D5;" />
            </winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Materials" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MaterialsPage">
            <winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE950;" />
            </winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Documentation" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:DocumentationPage">
            <winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE946;" />
            </winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
    </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
            <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemInvokedCommand}" />
        </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
    </Grid>
</winui:NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> NavigationView icons + text in compact mode

it's hard to make interface like the screenshot that you mentioned above, you need to edit the default [`NavigationViewItemPresenter`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/7ec5fb5b8c85ebe04d8498ee89f26d1b5259d948/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView_rs1_themeresources.xaml#L546) style, and set icon above and content bottom.

For making navigation like above, we suggest you custom side navigation with `SplitView` to replace default  NavigationView. and set `ListView` as pane content. Then you could design the nav item flexibly by customizing `ItemTemplate` .

For more detail please refer to Xaml-Controls-Gallery [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/ControlPages/SplitViewPage.xaml.cs).